# c# how to access data fields of the selected in DataGridView database record

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm new to the database programming, so I have probably very simple question.

On the form I have a DataGridView which shows all records from the SQL database, from single table. When I select a line (OnRowEnter event), I would like to display the same data in the textBoxes, which are not binded to the DataSource, but I do not know how to access the selected record and its fields.
I have seen many examples which use SQL statements, but is it the only way? Or is there a simpler method. I thought I should be able to access the current record and its fields almost directly? Is it possible?

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013

Thx in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string asd = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["NameOfColumn"].Value.ToString();
    }
```

You can access any column of any row by this line.

EDIT:
You just told me you want to populate 2 textboxes from database and on buttons(save - overwrite) you want to save/overwrite it. So why you do not populate it from database

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT TEXT1, TEXT2 FROM TABLE WHERE CONDITION", con))
    {
        FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(dr.Read())
        {
            textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
        }
    }
    con.close();
}
```

and then after user press save you just take whole text and update database

```
using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(connectionString))
{
    con.Open();
    using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCoimmand("UPDATE TABLE SET TEXT1 = @Text1, TEXT2 = @Text2 WHERE CONDITION))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text1", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Text2", textBox2.Text);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

if user is writing text in some other textbox and you want to add that text to current text in database so you just read text from database and put it in string, on that string you add string from user and save like that to database

Comment: Yes, I know this, but I would like to access via the database, as at the end I may need to replace the data of the current record with the new data.

Comment: You said it needs to display data in textBoxes which are not bound to datasource. What editing are you talking about and how it is going to be done?

Comment: I've got two text fields in the database table, and those two fields I would like to display in the textBoxes. Then the user can edit it and save as a new record or overwrite existing one. I do not want the user to use the DataGrid for editing.

Comment: And last peace, does he have 2 buttons (save - overwrite)?

Comment: Yes, "Save as new"  and "overwrite"

Comment: Thank you very much. Clear answer, now I understand. Best regards.